# $logged is returning 1 regardless if user logged in or not

Tags: php, smarty, prestashop

I added $logged variable to smarty like this in order to check if user logged in or not

```
$this->smarty->assign(array(      
                    'wppopup' => $wppopup,  
                    'logged' => $this->context->customer->isLogged(),          
                    'default_lang' => (int)$this->context->language->id,
                    'image_width' => Configuration::get('WPPOPUP_IMAGE_WIDTH'),
                    'image_height' => Configuration::get('WPPOPUP_IMAGE_HEIGHT'),
                    'id_lang' => $this->context->language->id,
                    'wppopup_image' => !Configuration::get('WPPOPUP_IMAGE_DISABLE') && file_exists('modules/wppopup/wppopup_image_'.(int)$id_shop.'.jpg'),
                    'image_path' => $this->_path.'wppopup_image_'.(int)$id_shop.'.jpg'
                )
        );
```

But when i use it `{if $logged}` in the template file it returns empty. Other variables work well.

Is there sth that is missing ?

Answer (score 1):

It's not a Smarty issue. You should check in PHP file where you want to assign to 'logged' what values are returned by `isLogged` method.

Use simple

```
var_dump($this->context->customer->isLogged());
```

to make sure what values are returned by this method so you can check.

When I use in PHP

```
$smarty->assign(array(                          
                    'logged1' => true,        
                    'logged2' => false
                )
        );
```

and in Smarty file:

```
{if $logged1}
is logged
{/if}

{if $logged2}
is logged too
{/if}
```

Output is

> is logged

So if you assign simple true and false to Smarty variables it works fine so probably isLogged method return some other values.

Comment: I tried, $logged returns 1 even if user logged in or not, what should i do ?

Comment: Do you mean `var_dump($this->context->customer->isLogged());` gives you always 1 even if user is not logged?

Comment: $this->context->customer->isLogged() and var_dump($this->context->customer->isLogged()) both gives 1 always

Comment: i think i got it, it is about the cache, how can i disable the cache ?

Comment: I don't know what cache you mean. You should probably look at your Prestashop documentation to do it.

Answer (score -1):

Try it this way

```
if($this->context->customer->isLogged() == true){
    $isLogged = "true";
}else{
    $isLogged = "false";
}

$this->smarty->assign(array(
    'wppopup' => $wppopup,  
    'logged' => $isLogged,  
    'default_lang' => (int)$this->context->language->id,
    'image_width' => Configuration::get('WPPOPUP_IMAGE_WIDTH'),
    'image_height' => Configuration::get('WPPOPUP_IMAGE_HEIGHT'),
    'id_lang' => $this->context->language->id,
    'wppopup_image' => !Configuration::get('WPPOPUP_IMAGE_DISABLE') && file_exists('modules/wppopup/wppopup_image_'.(int)$id_shop.'.jpg'),
    'image_path' => $this->_path.'wppopup_image_'.(int)$id_shop.'.jpg')
);
```

Comment: It doesn't change anything. Why you want to assign string true and false instead of bool anyway?